# how to send continous streams from a separate thread to activity

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-thread

I have started a thread which connected to bluetooth device and streams data. I actually started this thread from a service(Thread not started from activity). So know I need to communicate to activity to show the list of input streams. I am not sure if event bus can provide a such a high frequently changing data. Can some one give me a better existing examples of how to use display the streams.

Please don't ask me for the source code.

Comment: use the broadcast receiver in your activity.. and then send the broadcast from the thread in the service

Comment: I don't think broad cast receiver will be able to send high frequency data streams ? @santanuSur

Comment: yes may be not..

Comment: @pskink I didn't  understand the use of parcelfiledescriptor and auto close streams in my issue. can you help me with that.

Comment: have you tried an aidl interface?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Event bus can be a good solution, also check bound services:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to look into [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) from the Android architecture components. You can observe the result from the activity, and it will "unsubscribe" for you when needed (`onStop()`). You can read about the advantages on the link I provided.

You could extend a `LiveData` and implement the logic inside it (like [this example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html#extend_livedata)), or just use it to dispatch the updates, then observe it on the Activity. The `postValue()` method will ensure that it gets dispatched on the MainThread.

Comment: Hey I tried to use Live data but the initialization of live data from service or background thread but i was not able to work on it. Can you explain more about using Live data from a thread started by a service.